# Naurki.com has two new ad popups when the url is launched. How to handle this? Can enabling popup blocker in chrome via Chromeoptions will work?

Tags: selenium

I am using the below code to enable popup blocker. But this doesn't work.

```
Map<String, Object> prefs= new HashMap<String,Object>();
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.popups", 2);
ChromeOptions coptions= new ChromeOptions();
coptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
driver= new ChromeDriver(coptions);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple walkaround for this problem. We can find the window popups via WindowHandles and using a loop, we can switch to that window, close it and return back to the parent window. This also helps when the number of popup ads is varying.